# Azure deployment with PowerShell, "New-AzureDeployment : There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net/..."

Tags: powershell, deployment, azure

Following the guide and powershell script from this article,

```
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/
```

I've run into an extremely odd error:

9/4/2012 9:02 PM - Creating New Deployment: In progress
New-AzureDeployment : There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net/5921d8af-88a1-4f63-9673-5e1ae1df7e8a/services/storageservices/Build_2012-09-04_02-27.1/dist/LNEC_Admin.Azure.cspkg/keys that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

It's odd because we're on build "Build_2012-09-04_08-16.1", not the one mentioned in the URL above (which no longer even exists on the filesystem).  This is under Jenkins CI which runs under the NETWORK SERVICE account.  If I run it by hand with my own account the same error results, but with a lnecint in place of the build directory: https://management.core.windows.net/5921d8af-88a1-4f63-9673-5e1ae1df7e8a/services/storageservices/lnecint/keys

That keyword "lnecint" isn't mentioned anywhere in any config (I've searched every file on the entire machine and TFS server).  It was the name of a storage account, but it's long ago been deleted.

VS 2012, Azure SDK 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely an issue with your endpoint. Can you check what parameters you're passing to the "New-AzureDeployment" Cmdlet?

Comment: Forcing it to echo a copy out (after variable expansion):

New-AzureDeployment -Slot Staging -Package LNEC_Admin.Azure.cspkg -Configuration ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg -label "LNEC INT Deployment 86" -ServiceName int-lnec-admin

Comment: Just above it's running:

Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount intlnecdata -SubscriptionName "LNEC INT"

Comment: I believe what's happening (not sure why) is that your storage service name is being replaced by the package file name. The Cmdlet is trying to fetch storage account keys (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460785) and the URI for that is https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/storageservices/[service-name]/keys. If you notice the error, you'll see that [service-name] parameter is being replaced with the name of your package file.

Comment: Thank you!!  That sent me in the right direction.

The powershell code appeared to import the .publishsettings anew each time and explicitly select the service and storage accounts to use, however subscriptions are apparently cached by Windows as they are imported...and the "default" is used by the cmdlets.

After a few passes of creating new settings files, switching subscriptions, etc and the imported subscription info was all kinds of wrong.

The solution was nuke all subscription info with each run:

Get-AzureSubscription | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureSubscription $_.SubscriptionName }